# ILogger not returning Message and Object in JSON format

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog, structured-logging

Im trying to use ILogger the following way,

```
_logger.LogInformation("Logging info {someClass}", someClass);
```

But the output is just the object name.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please include the NLog.config. Have you configured `MaxRecursionLimit=10` for the JsonLayout: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout

Answer (score 6):

You probably like to destruct the class into properties.

That is opt-in, and can be enabled by using the `@`

So

```
_logger.LogInformation("Logging info {@someClass}", someClass);
```

See also: [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) 
and the [Message templates specs](https://messagetemplates.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much!. This solved my problem with not getting objects passed from ILogger to NLog.